# Having a little trouble understanding how HTTP Client is working (advice appreciated)

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, httpclient, webbrowser-control

so I am using c#, my goal is to enter some simple search in the Wikipedia search bar in the upper right. I want to use Gets and Posts with HTTP Client to do this. I am familiar with html agility pack for web scraping but this seems kinda more like browser automation as the site is still live and not just immediately parsed. Anyway, goal is to enter data into the wiki search box and then perhaps return the html code to see that it is in the box or either make it start the search.

I am very new to this and asking not for anyone to do it for me but maybe just references to code code bases if you know of examples of something like this on the internet. Or like a short example would help. Anything to point me in the right direction as I am a little confused and have been trying this for a while now. Thanks much!

Comment: You seem to (a little bit) be mixing up concerns that a browser would have (checking what's entered into a form on a page - which is unrelated to the transfer of data between client and server) and making actual requests. For me, searching on Wikipedia involves a GET request to `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=test&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go&wprov=acrw1_-1` (note my query "test" in the query string).

Comment: @Llama interesting, I think I get what ur making of this. I am thinking about it in the wrong way. I could kinda submit a string to a serein spot or something maybe. 

How did you create that query "test" string? ( am assuming that it will search test in the same spot I suggested, I think)

If I were to send this from a c# program then I guess I could just create a httpclient request or post.

Comment: I created it by opening Chrome's debugger and seeing what the first request as a result as submitting the request form was. You could also do this programmatically by looking at the HTML though. There is a form element with the action `/w/index.php` and an input box called `search` (which is what we see on the page).

Comment: @Llama Ah, ok. I think I am making progress. I opened the debugger and now through some searching figured out I can use the network tab. Using it to view the requests. I entered test in the box and hit enter. I can also see the request url the method the remote adress and headers and whatnot. Turnes out it adds php stuff and I don't have to even hit enter. strange. This is the link I got:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=test&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go&wprov=acrw1_-1
Would I need to target the search box to replicate this in c#?